# How to enable cache for localhost in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, http, cache

I setup a test website on `localhost:8022` and for some reason the css style sheets are not cached. The max age of a cache is set to 0 in the header `Cache-Control: max-age=0`:
[image]

If I visit the site with Chrome, cache is working. If I visit other websites in Firefox like `https://superuser.com` the cache is also working.

Why does Firefox send a `max-age=0` in the request header for the locahost website. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried to set an additional network name like `127.0.0.1 myserver.local` to your address in the `hosts` file (and also use this address for requests)? Then Firefox may see the site as non-local and uses caching.

Comment: @Robert I just tried that out, but it still won't cache.

Comment: Do you always have the developer panel open? There is an option that disabled caching if the developer panel is open: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027947/150978 (this option should be disabled by default).

Comment: @Robert the option is [unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuMhQ.png). For some reason, caching works on other sites on Firefox, but not for localhost.

Comment: You are using a query string "?ver=5.4.2" which usually the browser never caches.

Comment: @harrymc that is not true. See for example [here at super user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm7tn.png). The idea behind a query string after a css like "all.css?ver=5.4.2" is that it will be cached until the developer increases the version number to let the browser know it has to be re-cached.

Comment: The general rule says no caching. A website can override the default by using the HTML headers of `Cache-Control` and `Expires`. Different browsers might behave differently.

Comment: @harrymc I tried to google this and my result was that if you enter a url including a query string and hit enter, it will not be cached. But if the url is just requested in a webpage it will be cached (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83990/is-it-the-filename-or-the-whole-url-used-as-a-key-in-browser-caches). Anyway, also my css files that have no query string have `Cache-Control: max-age=0` set.